# expand a tensor in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

My hare-brained idea is to create a custom layer that allows me to programmatically add features to a model's output.

EDIT - My "O" output values (see image below) are ASCII values.  I want the "F"eature nodes to be 1 if the corresponding "O" nodes are alphabetic and 0 otherwise. In a previous experiment, the additional information made training much much better.

```
class Unpack_and_Categorize(keras.layers.Layer):
    
    def __init__(self, units=32, **kwargs):
        super(Unpack_and_Categorize, self).__init__(units, **kwargs)
        self.units = units
        self.trainable = False

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.weight = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.bias = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), trainable=True, dtype="float32"
        )

    def call(self, inputs):
        batch_size = inputs.shape[0]
        one_hot_size = self.units
        c = tf.constant([0] * (one_hot_size * batch_size), shape=(batch_size, one_hot_size))
        base_out = tf.tensordot(inputs, self.weight, axes = 1) + self.bias
        return tf.concat(base_out, c, shape=(batch_size, 2*one_hot_size))
```

This image shows what I am trying to accomplish.  My custom layer (right side) has 3 values that are densely connected to the previous layer.  But now I want to add three 3 more output values that are totally derived from the O1..3.  For example, I might set `Fx` to 1 if `Ox` was an even number.  This would be done in the `call` method.

So the challenge is that I don't want to hardcode the number of outputs. That is, if the input layer has 10 inputs, then the customer layer will have 20 values.  (The challenge that follows is 'will it back-prop, or simply explode...)

[image]

Here is an example where we see the "A" is categorized with a 1, while the punctuation and numeric are categorized with a 0.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to say exactly what you want to do without seeing all your code, but you need to make sure that all dimensions except the one you want to concatenate are the same:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def call(inputs):
    w_init = tf.random_normal_initializer()
    w = tf.Variable(
            initial_value=w_init(shape=(10, 10), dtype="float32"),
            trainable=True,
        )
    batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
    c = tf.constant([1.0] * (15 * tf.cast(batch_size, tf.float32)), shape=(batch_size, 15))
    print('Inputs: ',  inputs.shape)
    print('C: ', c.shape)
    return tf.concat((tf.tensordot(inputs, w, axes = 1) ,c), 1)

batch_size = 5
print('Result: ', call(tf.random.normal((batch_size, 10))).shape)
```

```py
Inputs:  (5, 10)
C:  (5, 15)
Result:  (5, 25)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll cogitate on this after work.

Comment: I edited the original post.

Comment: Could you maybe create a new question based on your edit ?

Comment: Can I just delete the first part of this one?

Comment: Sure, you can edit it but my answer is then no longer relevant..

Comment: I modified the question - no need for a new one, it's just you and me.

Comment: My original question was bad, I apologize.

Comment: Ok can you explain this part a bit more: For example, I might set Fx to 1 if Ox was an even number. This would be done in the call method. Still not understanding what exactly you want to do

Comment: Edit made, right at the top

Comment: Ok understand so actually you just want to apply a mask to your O output. My question is though how do you plan to find out if the output is an ASCII character if you are working with float values ?

Comment: Multiply them by 128 then round.  Or let the NN do that mutiplication.  Training should bludgeon the values into the appropriate ranges.

Comment: Ohh I see… ok will make a solution. What is your input shape and what output shape are you expecting from your layer ?

Comment: unspecified of course.  I want to be able to vary the network topology. The part I need help with is how to create the 3 extra F nodes in the example above.  I keep getting size mismatches when I try. The batch size has to be taken into account but this isn't available until calculation time.  That being said, if you can show me how it works for 5, I can figure out how to do it for 'n'. I think.